# Benefits of Functional decomposition and currying

Tags: java, functional-programming, java-8

I have a function, calculate(String A,int B) in legacy code

```
Double calculate(String A,int B) {
   if(A.equals("something")){  return B*1.02; }
   if(B.equals("some")) return B*1.0;
   else return B;
}
```

The calculation applied on B depends on the value of A.

In functional style I can break this into:

```
Function<String, Function<Integer,Double>> strategyA = (a)-> {
  if(A.equals("something")) return b -> b*1.02;
  if(B.equals("some")) return b -> return b -> b*1.0;
  else return b -> b;
}
```

Then instead of calling `calculate(a,b)` I would call

```
strategyA.apply(a).apply(b)
```

Is the second style better than first one. As per my understanding this involves Strategy pattern and Functional Decomposition and Currying.

If the second approach is indeed better, how would you convince someone?

Answer (score 3):

In Java, the preferred way of delivering a named piece of code is and stays the method. There is no reason to express a method as function, just to have “more functional style”. The reason, why function support was added to Java, is, that you sometimes want to pass a reference to the code to another method or function. In this case, the receiving method defines the required function signature, not the code you’re going to encapsulate.

So your `calculate` method may be referred to as an `ObjIntConsumer<String>`, if the receiving method only wants to pass pairs of `String` and `int` to it without being interested in the result. Otherwise, it may use a custom functional interface expressing the `(String,int) → Double` signature. Or when you accept boxing, `BiFunction<String,Integer,Double>` will do.

Currying allows you to reuse existing interfaces like `Function` to express functions with multiple arguments, when no builtin interface exists, but given the resulting generic signature, which will appear at least at one place in Java code using such a curried function, the readability suffers a lot, so in most cases, defining a new functional interface will be preferred over currying in most cases…

For other programming languages, having a different syntax and type inference for functional types (or having real function types in the first place, rather than settling on functional interfaces), this will be quite different.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with Holger that in most cases, it does not make sense to write code using functions just for the sake of using functional programming. Functions are just an additional tool that lets you write code such as collection processing in a nicer way.

There is one interesting thing about your example though, which is that you take the `String` parameter `a`, then perform some computation and then return another function. This can be *sometimes* useful if the first operation takes a long time:

```
Function<String, Function<Integer,Double>> f = (a) -> {
  if (some-long-computation(a)) return b -> b*1.02;
  if (some-other-long-computation(a)) return b -> return b -> b*1.0;
  else return b -> b;
}
```

When you then invoke `f` with the `String` argument, the function will run `some-long-computation` and `some-other-long-computation` and return the desired function:

```
Function<Integer,Double> fast = f.apply("Some input"); // Slow
Double d1 = fast.apply(123); // Fast!
Double d1 = fast.apply(456); // Fast!
```

If `f` was an ordinary method, then calling it twice as `f("Some input", 123)` and
`f("Some input", 456)` would be slower, because you'd run the expensive computations twice. Of course, this is something you can handle without functional programming too, but it is one place where returning a function actually fits quite nicely.

Comment: You could still have a method returning a `Function`…

Comment: @Holger the question is not about the syntax..rather its  about benefits of returning a function as result instead of directly computed value and about spreading method arguments over multiple functions.

Comment: Tomas has clearly stated one use case where this might actually make sense.

Comment: @Satyendra Kumar: there is a significant relationship to the syntax, as there are functional programming languages for which there is no difference between curried functions and functions with multiple parameters. So there, getting a partially applied function is as easy as omitting one or more parameters. In contrast, having to declare `Function<T1,Function<T2,Function<T3,Function<T4,Function<T5,Function<T6,R>>>>>>` to do a similar thing in Java *makes* a difference. If you only wanted to see some use case examples, your question is off topic for Stackoverflow.

Comment: In Tomas example it is useful *to return* a function, but since there is still no reason *to define* `f` as a function (instead of a method returning a function), there is no reason to have a curried function here.